# how can I call a vba function from within vlookup

Tags: excel, wrapper, vlookup, vba

I have the below formula which I think will work
     `=if(B1=1,fxcmde3(),if(B1=2,fxcmde4(),if(B1=3,fxcmde5(),if(B1=4,fxcmde6(),if(B1=    5,fxcmde7(),if(B1=6,fxcmde8(),””))))))`

where each fxcmde4() etc is a vba function such as

```
Function fxcmdc3() As Variant
fxcmdc3 = Sheets("Sheet8").Range("DC3").Value
End Function
```

however I am going to have to write about 1000-2000 variations of this to reference the 64 or so functions that I have. Additionally I will probably have oto write the formula out every time.

This is because I can't run the vba function by referencing a cell to it to make things quicker. If I did then `=AF3` would work where cell AF3  contains `fxcmde3()`  but this doesn't work , hence vlookup or anyother method of referring to this function won't work.

my excel formulas will be like `=if(B1=1,fxcmde3(),if(B1=2,fxcmde4(),if(B1=3,fxcmde5(),if(B1=4,fxcmde6(),if(B1=5,fxcmde7(),if(B1=6,fxcmde8(),””))))))`
for say cell `M2`
then in M3 all the way to M8 referrin gto e up to k
`=if(B1=1,fxcmdf3(),if(B1=2,fxcmdf4(),if(B1=3,fxcmdf5(),if(B1=4,fxcmdf6(),if(B1=5,fxcmdf7(),if(B1=6,fxcmdf8(),””))))))` 
then in `M3` I will have the same procedure ( referring e to k )except referring to `B2`

hence this will take forever all the way down to row M1000

B1 b2 TO b1000 WILL ONLY HAVE Values 1 - 7 to refer to the correspinding d to k hence I thin I could use a lookup or some expensive or time consuming wrapper function which I ahev no idea about ( hence why Im here ) to do this

Answer (score 0):

If all the functions you want to use are that simple, don't do it through VBA user defined functions. Just use normal excel references to sheets and cells.

`=IF(B1=1,Sheet8!$DC$3,If(B1=2,...)`

Or is there any reason why you want to avoid this method?

### Edit 1

Are you trying to reference the function in this manner?
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: yes because I need the cell pasted at the time I run the UDF. i.e when B1 changes to 1. For the returned value to stay there even if its value changes from where it is copied. I am thinking this might work if the UDF contains a cell reference in the brackets. Smething like `Function fxcmdc3(DC3) As Variant
fxcmdc3 = Sheets("Sheet8").Range("DC3").Value
End Function` although maybe not because I have like 56 UDF's to reference

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more. I didn't get it.

Comment: its basically I case of when I use your IF function when I delete Sheet8 DC3 after this value has been copied to where I write the formula. The value goes from where I write the formula. If I use my vba function (which is equivalent of right click copy ,paste special paste values) then it stays where the function leaves it from when the function was run initially. make sense?

Comment: actually I think I might have to only write the lines 6 times then I can copy paste to corresponding B1-B1000

Comment: I think I see what you want. But I must warn you, that your function is **not** equivalent to paste values. If the values you are referencing in your function change (the source ones) and a recalculate event occurs, the results (the output ones) will update accordingly. I recommend **using the formula**, **copy** where you need it, then **select everything** and then **paste as values**. This will get rid of the formulas and changes to source values will have no effect on output.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific about a recalculate event. Selecting everything and pasting values is impossible for me and I have it set up this way to avoid inefficiencies.

Comment: Sorry I was wrong about that. They do not update automatically, when set the way you have them set.

Comment: no problem. I think I might be able to manage the above through vopying and pasting. But obviously if anyone has knowledge about how to reference UDF's from other cells and how to do it then Im all ears

Comment: See the edit 1 in my answer. Is this what you are trying to achieve? In my case the references are working.